# How to speed up libreoffice? Libre office can't handle big files

Tags: libreoffice

When I add many pictures, LibreOffice slows down and becomes unusable. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (8GB RAM i7 4500)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed Up Libreoffice

Tools > Options Memory >

[image]

The best configuration depends on your computer specs.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: "Memory" is not on my menu O.o

Comment: Look for on “libre office”

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, disable the display of images:

[image]