# Can't open ODT large file in 16.04 after upgrade from 15.10

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice, odt

I have a large `ODT` file (37.3 MB) file which I can no longer open after upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04.  I am also unable to open a `.doc` copy of the file of 54.7 MB.  
Screen goes grey, and when I attempt to delete, I get message `Window not responding - Wait or Force Quit?`  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Could you link this file?

Comment: Is your hardware new or oldish? The gtk3 implementation of LibreOffice works better on newer hardware. If you don't have a GPU try launching LibreOffice in gtk2 mode as a workaround: `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk libreoffice --writer`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771091/how-to-speed-up-libreoffice-libre-office-cant-handle-big-files/771092#771092), I had similar problem before. Otherwise your document may be corrupted